# Second derivative of infinite sum

Tags: derivatives, summation

Is the following function: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{\sin(nx^2)}{1+n^4}}$$ 
Has a continuous second derivative in R? 
(If it was in $[-a,a]$ or for $\sin(nx)$ it was easy, but I'm not sure what to do with the derivative of the inner function)

Thanks! (Even just an answer of yes/no will help me because I'm not sure if there is a problem with the question or me :P )

Comment: Yes. If you know that the answer is positive when the function is restricted to $[-a,a]$, use that $f$ is $C^2$ on $\mathbb R$ if and only if $f$ is $C^2$ on every $(-a,a)$.

Comment: Why is it true? How can we show a uniform convergence in all R? (In [-a,a] we can say the if f(x)=Sum(Un(x)) than |Un(x)|<=a * 2n/(1+n^4) -> 0 yet we used the fact that |x|<=a )

Comment: Because being $C^2$ at a point $x$ is a local property, it does nor depend on the behaviour of the function outside of $(x-1,x+1)$, say.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it does (I'm only using the first derivative to find the second derivative):$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx^2)}{n^4+1}\rightarrow\frac{1}{n^4+1}\frac{d}{dx}\sin(nx^2)=\frac{1}{n^4+1}2nx*\cos(nx^2)$$ My arrow is supposed to mean that as it's a sum, you can get rid of (or recreate) the larger picture for the moment. $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx^2)}{n^4+1}\rightarrow\frac{2n}{n^4+1}\frac{d}{dx}x*\cos(nx^2)\rightarrow2nx*-\sin(nx^2)+1*\cos(nx^2)\rightarrow\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n\cos(nx^2)-4n^2x\sin(nx^2)}{n^4+1}$$ This seems to me to be a continuous second derivative.